# how to crop multiple images and how to run loop in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

filepreview is working dynamically but the issue is that when I run loop in jQuery it's not working. I want `#filepreview1` is coming dynamically in a loop. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

```
<p><img id="filePreview<?php echo $i; ?>" style="display:none;"/></p>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    //prepare instant image preview
    for(i=0;i<=5;i++){
    var p = $("#filePreview"+i);
    $("#fileInput"+i).change(function(){
        //fadeOut or hide preview
        p.fadeOut();

        //prepare HTML5 FileReader
        var oFReader = new FileReader();
        oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("fileInput"+i).files[0]);

        oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
            p.attr('src', oFREvent.target.result).fadeIn();
        };
    });

    //implement imgAreaSelect plugin
    $('img#filePreview'+i).imgAreaSelect({
        // set crop ratio (optional)
        //aspectRatio: '2:1',
        onSelectEnd: updateCoords
    });
}
});
```